# Segmentation fault Python

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, enthought

I have the Enthought Python Distribution installed.
Before that I installed Python2.7 and installed other modules (e.g. opencv). 
Enthought establishes itself as the default python. 
Called 7.2, but it is 2.7. 
Now if i want to import cv in the Enthought Python it always gives me the Segmentation fault Error.
Is there anyway to import cv in the Enthought Python ?
That would be awesome.
Also installing any new module into Enthought, seems to have the same error. 
Any solution for that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: This contains much too less information to be answered.

Comment: You are on windows, right? if so, add the windows tag.

Comment: If you installed opencv via homebrew, you may have compiled opencv against your system's regular python version instead of the Enthought python version.  This will give you a Segmentation Fault when ipython tries and fails to load the opencv.so file. (That's what happened for me.)  Homebrew's buildscript uses python-config to figure out where python is installed, but Enthought didn't ship with a python-config.  I had to modify homebrews build script by hardcoding the correct path and python_version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python only SEGFAULTs if

- There is error in a native extension DLL code loaded
- Virtual machine has bugs (it has not)

Run Python in -vvv mode to see more information about import issues.

You probably need to recompile the modules you need against the Python build you are using. Python major versions and architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit) native extensions are not compatible between versions.

Also you can use gdb to extract a C stack trace needed to give the exact data where and why it crashes.

There are only tips what you should do; because the problem is specific to your configuration only and not repeatable people can only give you information how to further troubleshoot the issue.  Because it is very likely that methods to troubleshoot issue given here might be too advanced, I just recommend reinstall everything.